# Automatic abbrev expansion as you type?

Tags: abbrev

Is `C-x '` the only way that abbrev expansion is invoked, or is there a way to expand abbrevs automatically, as you type, a bit like `company-mode` does.

Comment: Did you read the docs? Quote: `For example, you might define ‘foo’ as an abbrev
expanding to ‘find outer otter’.  Then you could insert ‘find outer
otter ’ into the buffer by typing ‘f o o <SPC>’.`

Comment: Still, you do not get automatic selection on-the-fly, right?.